# Inequality for derivatives of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

Let $V,W:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be two strongly convex functions coincinding at the common minimum point $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$:
$$ V(x_0)=W(x_0)\,,\ \nabla V(x_0)=\nabla W(x_0)=0 \;.$$
Suppose that
$$ V(x)\geq W(x)\,\ \forall\,x\in\mathbb R^n \;,$$
can we say that
$$ x_i\,\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}(x) \geq x_i\,\frac{\partial W}{\partial x_i}(x)\,\ \forall\,x\in\mathbb R^n \;?$$

I have in mind the example of $V,W$ being two quadratic functions, where this is clearly true. Is it still true in general? And if only $W$ is quadratic, $W(x)=V(x_0)+\alpha\,|x-x_0|^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, here is a counterexample in one dimension:
$$
 W(x) = x^2
$$
and $V$ defined by
$$
 V(x) = \begin{cases}
2 x^2 & \text { if } 0 \le x \le 1 \\
2+ 4(x -1) & \text { if } 1 \le x \le 3 \\
2+ 4(x -1) + 10(x-3)^2 & \text { if } x \ge 3 
\end{cases}
$$
and $V(-x) = V(x)$.

Then $V(0) = W(0) = 0$, $V'(0) =W'(0) = 0$, and $V(x) \ge W(x)$ for all $x  \in \Bbb R$. But for $2 < x < 3$ is
$$
 V'(x) = 4 < 2x = W'(x) \, .
$$

$V$ is linear on $[1, 3]$ but for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ is $\tilde V(x) = V(x) + \epsilon x^2$ strongly convex and still a counterexample.

This plot (created with wxMaxima) shows the graph of $V$ in blue and $W$ in red:

[image]